# Issue with Google Sign-In using Django-allauth and React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-allauth, django-socialauth

I am using bellow development environment:

- OS = Ubuntu 22.04.2
- Python = 3.10.6
- Django = 4.2.2
- djangorestframework = 3.14.0
- django-allauth = 0.54.0

I am running the Django server on localhost 8000 with SSL and the React server on 3000

The authentication is being handled by django-allauth and I am only using google and the local a local model for authentication.

I have registered both the front-end and back-end URLs with google credentials.
The Google credential configuration looks like
[google credential configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRBNi.png)

I am running the server with gunicorn with the below command:
`gunicorn --certfile=certs/server.crt --keyfile=certs/server.key mt_backend.wsgi:application`

When I try to log in with Google using the URL: /accounts/google/login/. I am able to log in successfully. However, when I try to POST the request to the same endpoint from my react app it throws a 304(Forbidden) error with backend logging:
`Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /accounts/google/login/`

Here's the code snippet for the login function used in React app:

```
  const handleGoogleLogin = () => {
    axios
      .post("https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

I have tried comparing both the session and found out, there is one additional csrfmiddlewaretoken getting passed on payload when I tried to use the Django url, but that token is missing when the request comes from the react app.

Network tab when the requests come from *https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/

[from backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IVCn.png)

Network tab when the requests come from *https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/

[from react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt3jE.png)

I also made sure the {% csrf_token %} is introduced inside the social login form that is used by the allauth library.

I need to invoke the Google sign-in prompt from my React app. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance